# how to read entire file having numbers separated by { , , } format in C?

Tags: c, file

I have a cipher text file which has number of values which looks like: 
number1: {n1,n2,...}% number2: {n1,n2,...} and so on.
I want to read this file in C.
Then extract n1, n2 till } is reached.any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide exact file format ? where are the newlines in your text ?  Simple reading the file and some string processing can serve your purpose

Comment: What are you reading the variables into? (an array, or...)

Answer (score 3):

If this sample file is in the correct format:

```
1: {2,3,4}% 5: {6,7,8}
```

Then you may extract the numbers using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char filename[] = "filename.txt";
  FILE *file;
  int n, num1, num2;

  file = fopen(filename, "r");

  while (fscanf(file, "%d: {%d", &num1, &num2) == 2)
  {
    printf("%d: ", num1);  
    printf("%d", num2);

    while(fscanf(file, ",%d", &num2) > 0)  
    {   
      printf(", %d", num2);
    }   

    fscanf(file, "}%% ");
    printf("\n");
  }

  fclose(file);
}
```

The variable `num1` holds the the numbers in front of the `{}`, e.g. `number1`, `number2`, ..., while `num2` holds the numbers inside the `{}`, e.g. `n1`, `n2`, ...

The corresponding output for the sample file given above would be:

```
1: 2, 3, 4
5: 6, 7, 8
```